# When I fix my menu, it cuts into my header image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, fixed

I am trying to fix my menu to the top of my website (which I have been able to figure out), but when I do that, it starts to overlap into my header image and it doesn't look that nice. I've been playing around with different fixes, but can't seem to crack it.

Here's the CSS I've added that makes it cut into the header. I've been able to move the menu up so it doesn't overlap the picture, but then it looks really weird because the text is basically at the very top of the screen so I undid that.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .site-top {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

Here are some pictures so you can see what I'm seeing. 
This is what it looks like normally:
[without the added css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQWzx.png)

Here's what it looks like with the new code:
[with the added css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEvgs.png)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Edited to add: This is a Wordpress.com site where I can only add custom CSS and am not able to access the entire code, so I don't know how to show code for the header and menu. My website is mathbythemountain.com

Comment: Can you include the html for the menu and header image in your question?

Comment: Post more code instead of only pictures. We cant know if only your media querie is the problem.

Comment: It's on a wordpress site where I can only add custom CSS and am not able to access the entire code, so I don't know how to do that. I know you can do ctrl+U to view things.

My website is mathbythemountain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was taking up space in the DOM before you made it fixed. Upon adding `position: fixed`, it becomes absolutely positioned and to every other element in the normal flow of the document, it doesn't exist. You'll need to add a top margin or padding to the body or whatever that top element is in order to make it look the same again.

Comment: Not separate enough to be a separate answer, but you may find changing `position:fixed` to something else to be helpful.  You can find more about positioning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thank you, I was able to add the following code and this fixed it. 

.site-header {
  margin-top: 55px;
}